# why is it possible to pass a file as a string to the open function

Tags: python

Can someone help me around this logic, I have seen in other people code, they usually pass an object in string representation to a function. E.g the open file function.

```
txtFile = open("fruits.txt")
print(txtFile.read())
```

Why is `fruits.txt` in quotes and when should an object of anything be in quotes when passing it into another function parameter can someone also please give me more examples when should

I know that for example using a print function this can in a string or an object.

```
name = 'sam'
print(name, 'sam')
output >>>>> sam sam.
```

The object name, when passed to the print method, isn't placed in a string format, however, the example of an open file with fruits.txt is enclosed into a string format. and if I placed the name in a string like

```
name = 'sam'
print('name', 'sam')
output >>>>> name sam.
```

Comment: If you quote it, it's a string. If you don't quote it, it's a variable.

Comment: If you're having trouble with this, you need to review the basic language syntax. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: And note that a string is an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fruits.txt` isn't a variable, it's a filename. If you removed the quotes, you'd get an error:

```
>>> open(fruits.txt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fruits' is not defined
```

When you pass `open` a string, it takes that string and asks the OS to open the file by that name.

It seems like your fundamental misunderstanding is that variables are expanded inside strings, or that strings and variables are interchangeable in any way - they're not. If you "place a variable in a string" it's a string, not a variable.

On the other hand, there are f-strings, which allow variable interpolation inside a string:

```
>>> name = 'Sam'
>>> f'My name is {name}'
'My name is Sam'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar commented, if it's in quotes it's a string, otherwise it's a variable. People commonly use a file path in the form of a string because it's a simple way to open a file that will only be opened in one spot. If you were going to open the same file multiple times throughout the program you could use a variable instead, like this:

```
filename = "fruits.txt"
txtFile = open(filename)
print(txtFile.read())
```

Comment: I added an example cause it wasn't clear what you meant when I read it at first

Comment: @Mr.Brad why put the fruits.txt in a string to begin with and why can't you just call fruits.txt in the open function or why can't you just say filename = fruits.txt and why use filename = 'fruits.txt'?

Comment: @ganiyu You would put it in a string because you can't say `filename = fruits.txt`. text needs (at least practically) to be stored as a string, using the quotes. Without quotes, the interpreter will think you're trying to assign the attribute `txt` on the `fruits` object to the variable `filename` The example there is only if you're going to reuse the filename variable.

Comment: @Brad thank you, also what other forms of python syntax require to place an object into two string besides opening a file. I get the above point on the open file, also can you get me straight on other forms of python function for example this is an machine learning cyberbullying code,   print("Text message received {}".format(payload.decode('utf8'))). Why does decode takes in a string format of utf8 and when and why does quotes takes in the string value and why cant one pass it as just utf8 with doing 'utf8'